# Нужны ли кавычки?

Tags: орфография, пунктуация

*Полученную систему «капля марганца – порция металлического расплава» усредняют и приводят в равновесие*

Answer (score 1):

Я бы кавычки сохранил.
Не знаю, можно подвести этот случай под конкретные рекомендации, но тут без кавычек текст становится просто нечитабельным. Как вариант - выделение курсивом.